# Cannot get authorization dialog to show with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

I've got a Google Apps Script that I have been working on to manage an event's resources - it's working fine I'm hitting an API and updating the sheet with my Python code.

I then added functionality to notify users via email that a video is ready to be approved. I've already seen the authorisation dialog and allowed the script to use my Gmail account etc.

But when running my script with the installable trigger added it's showing this:

> The script doesn't have permission to perform that action. Required permission: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify || https://mail.google.com/ || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.addons.current.action.compose) at onCellEdit(Code:60)

In my StackDriver Error logs.

I cannot get the Google Apps script to re-authorise the Gmail app I wrote to save my life. Does anyone have experience with this and know how to force the script reauthorization?

Comment: Add the scopes in manifest manually or try removing all the scopes in. manifest....

Answer (score 4):

You can try invalidating your authorization with [`ScriptApp.invalidateAuth()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#invalidateAuth()).

Comment: This helped me too. Seems like a hack though. Why doesn't it "just work" - as in go through re-authorization when it needs to?