# Not allowed to ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss) - despite oauthScopes. What am I missing?

Tags: google-apps-script

To avoid re-adding a trigger every time I open a spreadsheet, I want to check if it already exists.

From [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getUserTriggers(Spreadsheet)) I have:

```
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var triggers = ScriptApp.getUserTriggers(ss);
```

The required authorization scope is: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp`

Which I have added to the appsscript.json like so:

```
(...)
"oauthScopes": [
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"
]
(...)
```

Despite that I still get this error (translated from danish):

```
You don't have permission to call 
ScriptApp.getUserTriggers.
Required permissions: 
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp 
at onOpen(get-form-submit-and-update-sheet:4)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The function named `onOpen` is not allowed to use any function requiring authorization when invoked by opening the spreadsheet, unless you have created an installed trigger for it. Which you should not do, because you are still using a reserved name `onOpen`, which **always** binds the simple trigger too. If you install a trigger, then change OAuth scopes, it is absolutely not hackish that the trigger must be reinstalled - you changed the approved scopes!

Comment: Thanks @tehhowch - I guess my expectations are wrong. How would you make sure that you have a trigger installed exactly once, when you open the sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52276300/532238

Adding

```
ScriptApp.invalidateAuth();
```

As the first line in my onOpen() function.

Lets you re-authorize - seems like a hack to me though.